# How to determine the User account that causes the many mysql and apache processes?

Tags: process, apache-httpd, mysql

I have a server with no more that 40 websites on it. Many are Wordpress which is a high resource CMS.

I used to get alerts of the sites going down a lot. Look like MySQL crashing. It was a 8Gb server (on Linode). I decided to increase it to 16Gb thinking there are too many sites on it. It still crashes and all sites go down, multiple times a day.

As its only a web server, its likely one or some of the sites are just high usage sites.

But when I look at top or htop for the User causing all the 100% CPU and max RAM, its all mysql and apache.

The mysql and apache users must be running from an actual website which can be attributed to a User account, but I do not know how to link it back to that User. htop and top don't show the user that is running the apache or mysql process.

Does anyone know how I can view what User account is causing all the MySQL and apache processes, so I can determine if that user needs to go it own server for using high resources, then the rest of the sites should be fine.

Here are the lines from htop, but there are loads more than this for mysql and apache, this is just what I can see and copy from the visible part:

Thanks

```
  PID USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
16769 mysql      20   0 9071M 2437M  4728 S  0.0 15.2  0:00.00 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
16770 mysql      20   0 9071M 2437M  4728 S  0.0 15.2  0:00.77 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
16771 mysql      20   0 9071M 2437M  4728 S  0.0 15.2  0:02.79 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
16772 mysql      20   0 9071M 2437M  4728 S  0.0 15.2  0:03.00 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
16795 mysql      20   0 9071M 2437M  4728 S  0.0 15.2  0:33.53 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
16796 mysql      20   0 9071M 2437M  4728 S  0.0 15.2  0:42.89 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
16797 mysql      20   0 9071M 2437M  4728 S  0.0 15.2  0:00.32 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
16798 mysql      20   0 9071M 2437M  4728 S  0.0 15.2  0:11.65 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
16799 mysql      20   0 9071M 2437M  4728 S  0.0 15.2  0:00.46 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
16992 mysql      20   0 9071M 2437M  4728 S  0.0 15.2  0:00.56 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
24061 mysql      20   0 9071M 2437M  4728 S  0.0 15.2  0:00.56 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
24120 mysql      20   0 9071M 2437M  4728 R 15.4 15.2  0:01.30 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
24173 mysql      20   0 9071M 2437M  4728 S  7.4 15.2  0:00.48 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
24179 mysql      20   0 9071M 2437M  4728 S  9.1 15.2  0:01.18 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
24194 mysql      20   0 9071M 2437M  4728 S  0.0 15.2  0:00.68 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
24202 mysql      20   0 9071M 2437M  4728 S  5.7 15.2  0:00.47 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
24364 mysql      20   0 9071M 2437M  4728 S  0.0 15.2  0:04.28 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
24447 mysql      20   0 9071M 2437M  4728 S  0.0 15.2  0:00.73 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
16723 mysql      20   0 9071M 2437M  4728 S 38.2 15.2  3h33:12 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log

  PID USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
22949 apache     20   0 2141M 62624  9384 S  0.0  0.4  0:00.05 /usr/sbin/httpd.worker
22950 apache     20   0 2141M 62624  9384 S  0.0  0.4  0:00.06 /usr/sbin/httpd.worker
22951 apache     20   0 2141M 62624  9384 S  0.0  0.4  0:00.09 /usr/sbin/httpd.worker
22952 apache     20   0 2141M 62624  9384 S  0.0  0.4  0:00.07 /usr/sbin/httpd.worker
22953 apache     20   0 2141M 62624  9384 S  0.0  0.4  0:00.15 /usr/sbin/httpd.worker
22954 apache     20   0 2141M 62624  9384 S  0.0  0.4  0:00.05 /usr/sbin/httpd.worker
22955 apache     20   0 2141M 62624  9384 S  0.0  0.4  0:00.05 /usr/sbin/httpd.worker
22956 apache     20   0 2141M 62624  9384 S  0.0  0.4  0:00.07 /usr/sbin/httpd.worker
22957 apache     20   0 2141M 62624  9384 S  0.0  0.4  0:00.08 /usr/sbin/httpd.worker
22958 apache     20   0 2141M 62624  9384 S  0.0  0.4  0:00.09 /usr/sbin/httpd.worker
22959 apache     20   0 2141M 62624  9384 S  0.0  0.4  0:00.09 /usr/sbin/httpd.worker
22960 apache     20   0 2141M 62624  9384 S  0.0  0.4  0:00.07 /usr/sbin/httpd.worker
22961 apache     20   0 2141M 62624  9384 S  0.0  0.4  0:00.07 /usr/sbin/httpd.worker
22962 apache     20   0 2141M 62624  9384 S  0.0  0.4  0:00.05 /usr/sbin/httpd.worker
22963 apache     20   0 2141M 62624  9384 S  0.0  0.4  0:00.08 /usr/sbin/httpd.worker
22964 apache     20   0 2141M 62624  9384 S  0.0  0.4  0:00.10 /usr/sbin/httpd.worker
22965 apache     20   0 2141M 62624  9384 S  0.0  0.4  0:00.06 /usr/sbin/httpd.worker
22966 apache     20   0 2141M 62624  9384 S  0.0  0.4  0:00.07 /usr/sbin/httpd.worker
22967 apache     20   0 2141M 62624  9384 S  0.0  0.4  0:00.05 /usr/sbin/httpd.worker
22968 apache     20   0 2141M 62624  9384 S  0.0  0.4  0:00.09 /usr/sbin/httpd.worker
22969 apache     20   0 2141M 62624  9384 S  0.0  0.4  0:00.05 /usr/sbin/httpd.worker
22970 apache     20   0 2141M 62624  9384 S  0.0  0.4  0:00.06 /usr/sbin/httpd.worker
22971 apache     20   0 2141M 62624  9384 S  0.0  0.4  0:00.09 /usr/sbin/httpd.worker
22972 apache     20   0 2141M 62624  9384 S  0.0  0.4  0:00.07 /usr/sbin/httpd.worker
22973 apache     20   0 2141M 62624  9384 S  0.0  0.4  0:00.04 /usr/sbin/httpd.worker
22946 apache     20   0 2141M 62624  9384 S  0.0  0.4  0:02.16 /usr/sbin/httpd.worker
23094 apache     20   0 2141M 64236  9396 S  0.0  0.4  0:00.10 /usr/sbin/httpd.worker
23095 apache     20   0 2141M 64236  9396 S  0.0  0.4  0:00.07 /usr/sbin/httpd.worker
23096 apache     20   0 2141M 64236  9396 S  0.0  0.4  0:00.05 /usr/sbin/httpd.worker
23097 apache     20   0 2141M 64236  9396 S  0.0  0.4  0:00.10 /usr/sbin/httpd.worker
23098 apache     20   0 2141M 64236  9396 S  0.0  0.4  0:00.06 /usr/sbin/httpd.worker
23099 apache     20   0 2141M 64236  9396 S  0.0  0.4  0:00.07 /usr/sbin/httpd.worker
```

Comment: Where are these users? some machine, or remote?

Comment: This may be relevent: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XiFkyR35v2Y

Comment: All machine users, they are Linux users. When you add a new website it creates a user for that website. The users are still listed further below, for PHP processes.

Answer (score 0):

For **MySQL/MariaDB**, you can use [show processlist](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/show-processlist/) command

```
mysql> SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
+------+------+-----------+------+---------+------+----------+-----------------------+
| Id   | User | Host      | db   | Command | Time | State    | Info                  |
+------+------+-----------+------+---------+------+----------+-----------------------+
| 8454 | root | localhost | NULL | Query   |    0 | starting | SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST |
+------+------+-----------+------+---------+------+----------+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

For **Apache**, you can use [server-status](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_status.html)

Comment: SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST does not work though. At the moment I have a lot of those mysql processes in htop, but using SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST shows only 1 or 2 mysql queries running.

Comment: +--------+-----------------+-----------+-------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| Id     | User            | Host      | db    | Command | Time | State | Info             |
+--------+-----------------+-----------+-------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
|    270 | linode-longview | localhost | NULL  | Sleep   |    3 |       | NULL             |
| 321269 | root            | localhost | mysql | Query   |    0 | NULL  | SHOW PROCESSLIST |
+--------+-----------------+-----------+-------+---------+------+-------+------------------+

Comment: Somtimes when I run it frequently, the odd user account mysql process pops up, but the list is still long in htop.